# mvc4 - display text from ienumerable, not value

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an IEnumerable

```
 public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getDefaultCraft
    {
        get
        {
            List<SelectListItem> defaultCrafts = new List<SelectListItem>();
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "BOTTLEWATCH", Value = "1" });
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "CLERK", Value = "2" });
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "EXPEDITOR", Value = "4" });
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "CRANE OPERATOR", Value = "3" });
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "FIELD ACCOUNTANT", Value = "5" });
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "FOREMAN – CRANE/RIGG", Value = "6" });
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "WELDER", Value = "7" });
            return defaultCrafts;
        }
    }
```

with a dropdown on one form

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(q1 => q1.positionAppliedFor, ORCA.Models.lookUps.getDefaultCraft)
```

on another form I would like to display the text.
This displays the value `@Html.Label("Position", cf.positionAppliedFor, new { style = "width:3in;display:inline-block" })`  How can I get the text?

Answer (score 0):

The value is the only thing posted back from the form for saving.  You would need to create a function/dictionary to translate the value back to text.  Or have the text and value be the same and store this in your backend system for later retrieval.

One potential solution would be the following:

```
public static string GetDefaultCraftByValue(int id){
 switch(id){
   case 1:
    return "BOTTLEWATCH";
   case 2:
    return "CREEK";
   //etc....
 }
}
```

Then in the other function you defined, you could update this to be the following

```
 public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getDefaultCraft
    {
        get
        {
            List<SelectListItem> defaultCrafts = new List<SelectListItem>();
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = GetDefaultCraftByValue(1), Value = "1" });
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = GetDefaultCraftByValue(2), Value = "2" });
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = GetDefaultCraftByValue(3), Value = "4" });
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = GetDefaultCraftByValue(4), Value = "3" });
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = GetDefaultCraftByValue(5), Value = "5" });
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = GetDefaultCraftByValue(6), Value = "6" });
            defaultCrafts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = GetDefaultCraftByValue(7), Value = "7" });
            return defaultCrafts;
        }
    }
```

Lastly, in your view (or whereever you populate your view model)

```
@Html.Label("Position", GetDefaultCraftByValue(cf.positionAppliedFor), new { style = "width:3in;display:inline-block" })
```

This gives you one place that defines the mapping from the numerical value to text (DRY) as well as accomplished what you need as far as the display perspective is concerned.